# What is Java BE?

Tags: java

What is Java BE? I've seen it a couple of times in articles. But I cannot find information. Is it a new type of JDK? Or is it just a typo? Thanks.

Comment: Browser Edition I think. [See this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/is_javabe_justified1).

Comment: Have you got links to the articles where you saw it?

Comment: It could be somthing with Java Bean oder Bean Enterprise.

Comment: I think it can be for Java Back-End

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java BE stands for **Java Browser Edition**. It was an edition of Java with a limited set of libraries, in order to make the JRE package very small, such as few MegaBytes of size, instead of the standard package that is around 100 MegaBytes of size. You can find an interesting article [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/04/java_2_browser.html).

I said 'it was' because it seems the project was abandoned by Oracle, because there's no page or documentation on their website about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite convinced it stands for Java Back-End as @JoseLinares suggested

Answer (score -1):

I believe it refer to java Back End in general where i work they use to need java be developers as example and we work mostly with spring.